# ls -l /proc/self | increamental PID?

Tags: linux, command-line, process, proc

Each time, when the command`ls -l /proc/self` is executed, the link points to process who's PID keeps increasing. Why is this so ? Is it the PID of the `ls` command ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's the PID of [ls](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html).

POSIX defined `ls` as an external command, so anytime you run `ls`, the shell must create new process and run `ls` in that process.

To do that, the shell will call [execve()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html) system call:

```
$ strace ls -l /proc/self
execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "-l", "/proc/self"], [/* 76 vars */]) = 0
```

You can see, after new process was created, `/proc/self` belongs to context of that process, so it was expanded to the PID of `ls`.

Comment: But why is it increasing ?

Comment: @kesari: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446727/how-does-linux-determine-the-next-pid for more details.

Comment: thank you @cuonglm ! I could find a simpler answer here http://superuser.com/questions/135007/how-are-pids-generated

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's the PID of `ls`:

> **/proc/self**
>   This directory refers to the process accessing the /proc file system, and is identical to the /proc directory named by the process ID of the same process.

(from [`man 5 proc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc))

`/proc/self` is a symbolic link to `/proc/PID` for the PID of the process that accesses the link, by the magic of the `proc` filesystem.

In your case, that process is `ls`, and so each time you run the command you get a different PID (which tends to increase).